# Making an "or" KeyBind

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, keyboard

I'm attempting to write a KeyBind to Minecraft that will function as an 'or' statement (similar to coding). All I want is the sneak to be able to be LShift or RShift. Is there anyway - external program or not- that I can write a custom KeyBind?

Comment: What keyboard are you using? Some come with software that can change the function of each key.

Comment: Probably solvable with Autohotkey, most keybind macros are.

Comment: @Crafter0800 Using a Razer Ornata Chroma

Comment: @David I will post an answer this afternoon, I think this can be achieved using Razer Synapse, but I will check :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so first off you'll need razer synapse, this comes by default with any Razer kit you own. If you don't have it, download it [here](https://www.razerzone.com/synapse)

Once you've done this, open it then navigate to your keyboard tab, which should look like this:[image]
Then you want to click on the "LShift" key on the panel, Then assign the key as a "KEYBOARD FUNCTION", then, when it asks what key you want to rebind it to, rebind it to "RShift". It should now look like this:

[image]

Then, in Minecraft, bind your shift key to RShift, and whenever you press Lshift razer synapse will press Rshift, and if you press Rshift it will press Rshift.

Comment: Are they still doing that creepy forced online registration thing?  If so, that's something for users to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Your question might already be answered, but you can accomplish this really easily in AutoHotkey. All you need is a script with this:

```
RShift::LShift
```

This will make it so when you press RShift it presses LShift. LShift works as normal. You could reverse this if you wanted, or take it a step further and limit the script to only work in Minecraft, ie:

```
#IfWinActive, Minecraft ; Check that Minecraft is the active window.
RShift::LShift  ; RShift sends LShift
```

I'm sure your Razer keyboard's software can do what you want, but if you want to get into AutoHotkey it's a pretty powerful program and fantastic at setting up more complex key remappings.